# Trying to get rid of buffers with :%bd fails

Tags: buffers

I have trouble with buffers in Vim (8.0 on a rhel8 server) apparently. That said ... I was not aware of the exitance of buffers before facing this problem. So as you can see, my expertise in vim is limited.

I got in contact via en error poppig up when tring to `:q` a file which I am allowed to edit via `systemctl edit --full postgresql@.service` which uses vim to edit `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@.service`. Due to restrictions in my environment I do not have any write access beyond that in `/etc`

`E173: 2 more files to edit`

so I learned that buffers may be my problem

```
:ls
  1 %a   "/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@test.servicee356346753c261c9" line 1
  2      "/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@plakoda.servicee9258362d8896077" line 0
  3      "/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@plakodamvp.service19f58985a72e1639" line 0
```

now ... I found that `:bd` or `:%bd` should be the way to getting rid of those. However it does not work. `:%bd` says `3 buffers deleted` and shows an empty file. It I try to get out of this `:q` I am getting a new `E173 2 more files to edit`. the only way getting out of this is a `:q!`.

Entering the file I wanted to work on again shows

```
:ls
  1 %a   "/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@test.servicee6523c2bbef84935" line 1
  2      "/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@plakoda.service857bcb8fb3ec8bd8" line 0
  3      "/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@plakodamvp.serviceaf054a3401922b7a" line 0
```

so I am back to where I startet.

Is it the restricted access to the location of that file I am trying to work on, which may prevent the buffers from being deleted? Is there any way around this?

---

Addition:

I may be worth mentioning that apparently files listed in the buffers list (i.e. `/etc/systemd/system/.#postgresql@test.servicee6523c2bbef84935`
) do not exist.
however:

```
$ ls -la /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@*.service*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 965 21. Sep 10:08 /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@plakodamvp.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 933 21. Sep 09:18 /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@plakoda.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 938  9. Sep 15:25 /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 922 21. Sep 09:16 /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@test.service
```

also a swap file matching somewhat that naming schema (`.#postgresql@test.service4838413f9bf526f5.swp`) exists

Comment: What happens if you do `:wa` and then `:qa`?

Comment: I exit the file. buffers survive though

Comment: the buffers referr to other files, then the one I am working on actually. When opening those there is only one buffer listed. I would believe that is fine because it represents the current open file which potentially may be edited.

Comment: sorry `:bd` & `%bd` is what I mean. Corrected that in the question

Comment: @vrms Top tip: if you ever see an error of which you're unsure of the meaning, you can see more info by checking it in the documentation. In this instance: `:help E173`.

Comment: @vrms The files don't exist after you exit Vim (or before you enter it) because systemctl creates `"temporary files which will be written to the real location if the editor exits successfully"`.

Comment: I would bet that systemctl, like sudoedit, opens a regular file with a similar name and the moves it on top of the original, hence the names.

Comment: I highly urge you to read/watch http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `systemctl` is opening Vim with three ["arguments"](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#arglist), and Vim then prevents you from exiting until you have visted all these files with the `:n` command.

If you do want to exit without editing the files, just type `:q` again and it should work. (Or, as you mentioned in your question, and as [kadekai suggested in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38610/trying-to-get-rid-of-buffers-with-bf-fails/38611?noredirect=1#comment70499_38610), you can tell Vim from the outset that you want to ignore the unedited files in the arglist by using `:q!` or `:qa`.)

So your `:%bd` command is *working*. If you try `:ls` again afterwards, you will see that the buffers are no longer in the buffer list. But they are still in the `argument list`, which is a different thing. You can use the [`:args`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aargs) command to view the argument list.

This is explained in [`:help E173`](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#E173) and [`:help arglist-quit`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_07.txt.html#arglist-quit).

The argument list is introduced in [section 07.2 of the user manual](https://vimhelp.org/usr_07.txt.html#07.2).

Comment: Upvoted. But I asked OP to try (`:wa` and) `:qa`, and they said it didn't work. Why would that be?

Comment: @kadekai Ignore my comment above. `:qa` works (without the unnecessary `:wa`), but the OP said that _does_ work. When they say the buffers "survive", I'm presuming they just mean if they run the same `systemctl` command again all three files are opened again.

Comment: "OP" is me? regarding `:wa` & `:qa` ... when I type `:wa` actually nothing happens after pressing Enter. When I do `:qa` after that I exit the file. And 'yes'. When I repoen the initial file the 3 buffers appear again on `:ls`

Comment: @vrms There's no issue here. Vim is doing what systemctl is asking it to do. There are three arguments in the list, and if you want to quit without editing them, you have to tell it that in one of the three ways suggested above.

Comment: @vrms "OP" is short for "original poster". When people use it on this site they mean the person that asked the question.

Comment: so I can get around this as described. That much ist true. I just did not think of this being a desired situation. Foremost it is a bit irritating, but I can live with that. Seems there is no solution the get rid of those files. I doubt however that `systemctl edit --full` passed those other files as arguments to vim. I can't see any sense in that. But that may be a different discussion. thx everybody

Comment: @vrms You _can_ get rid of the files by altering the arglist. One way would be with the command `:args %`, which replaces the current contents of the arglist with just the current file. Why do you believe that `systemctl` isn't adding the files to the arglist? Do the files appear in the arglist even when invoking vim with an explicit `vim` command? It's possible, although I think less likely, that something else in your Vim configuration is adding the files. Do the files appear if you run `vim --clean` to ignore your config?

Comment: @vrms This is outside the scope of this site, but is your `systemctl` command definitely correct? I don't know much about systemctl, but reading the man page, it looks as though `postgresql@.service ` might not the name of a service, but instead the name of a unit template?

Comment: I understand the matter now a little better. 1. yes it is a unitfile I am trying to edit. The problem really is the * in the filename. This causes as you have suspected not only a single file but several ones, which leads to the buffer situation. The core problem is that I should edit a unit file without the `*` (`postgresql@.service`). That, however, does not work. Unfortunately I have no access rights to `/etc/systemd` whatsoever and will have to talk to the admins able to solve this. I have learned quite a bit & apologize whether I was seeing a vim problem, where there actually was none.